# cx_freeze deployment: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pyodbc

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-freeze

I was struggling with the following runtime exception and have found a solution, but I don't really understand why the solution works.  Anyway, I am posting my code and the solution in case it helps anyone else.  If anyone understands exactly why this fixes the issue please share your thoughts.  The exception occurs at runtime with code packaged by cx_freeze.

Here is the exception:

```
---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
    exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "c:\fccc\svn\shared\py\idw_jobs_ui.py", line 21, in <module>
    import sqla_declaratives.idw.bods_jobs.dag_ctrl as dc
  File "C:\fccc\svn\shared\py\sqla_declaratives\idw\bods_jobs\dag_ctrl.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sqla_utils.sqla_base import IdwBodsJobsBase
  File "C:\fccc\svn\shared\py\sqla_utils\sqla_base.py", line 74, in <module>
    class ClarityDboBase():
  File "C:\fccc\svn\shared\py\sqla_utils\sqla_base.py", line 77, in ClarityDboBase
    engine = sqla.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, fast_executemany=True)#, echo = True) # uncomment to see all SQL
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 61, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "C:\apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 268, in load
    "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pyodbc

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Here is the original Python cx_freeze script (which did not work):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

buildOptions = dict(excludes = ['scipy'
                                  , 'PyQt5'
                                  , 'matplotlib'
                                  , 'numpy'
                                  , 'notebook'
                                  , 'jedi']
                    , namespace_packages = ['sqla_utils'
                                            , 'sqla_declaratives']
                    )

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

py_app_to_build = os.path.join(os.environ['IDW_HOME']
                               , 'shared'
                               , 'py'
                               , 'idw_jobs_ui.py'
                               )

executables = [
    Executable(script=py_app_to_build
               , base=base
               , targetName = 'idw_pltfrm_edtr.exe')
]

setup(name='idw_pltfrm_edtr',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'IDW Platform Editor',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Comment: Do you have a diff between the non-working code and the working code? That would offer the most insight.

Answer (score 2):

So what is happening here is that SQL Alchemy is attempting to load the MS SQL python driver and it is not being found.

To resolve the problem I originally explicitly attempted to include the python pyodbc Microsoft SQL Server driver in the cx_freeze script, but I could see that in the original cx_freeze package it was already there under lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql.  If you look carefully at the original exception it matches this path.  So I don't see why the exception was occurring.

The solution was to add

```
packages = ['sqlalchemy', 'pyodbc']
```

to the build options in the cx_freeze script.  Note that both packages are required!  Only adding one or the other results in different runtime errors.  So this code is identical to the original with the addition of this one line.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

buildOptions = dict(excludes = ['scipy'
                                  , 'PyQt5'
                                  , 'matplotlib'
                                  , 'numpy'
                                  , 'notebook'
                                  , 'jedi']
                    , packages = ['sqlalchemy', 'pyodbc'] #fixed issue both are needed!
                    , namespace_packages = ['sqla_utils'
                                            , 'sqla_declaratives']
                    )

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

py_app_to_build = os.path.join(os.environ['IDW_HOME']
                               , 'shared'
                               , 'py'
                               , 'idw_jobs_ui.py'
                               )

executables = [
    Executable(script=py_app_to_build
               , base=base
               , targetName = 'idw_pltfrm_edtr.exe')
]

setup(name='idw_pltfrm_edtr',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'IDW Platform Editor',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

I diff'd the before and after install output from cx_freeze and I don't see any differences that to me explain exactly why this resolves the problem.  There were a few differences of course, but I just don't see why they did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that need pyodbc package when sqlalchemy creating engine (dependencies). Install pyodbc package, then make sure your ODBC driver is installed.